# Paypal payment screen showing different price than i'm receiving in my paypal account

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am editing a wordpress plugin which accepts paypal payments.
Buy default this plugin gives only subscription option, while I want to give an offer to buy additional services which I don't want to list on subscription page... so just right on confirmation page.. before paypal screen I added a new form.. which pulls data from db and shows .. i.e

```
  checkbox = additional-product-1 +$25
  checkbox = additional-product-2 +$15
```

So.. on submitting page .. i'm seeing added $25 or $15 on paypal payment screen.

[image]

On paypal screen..

> you can see $30 .. which is addition to $5 (subscription) +
> $25 (additional+product-1 )

So.. I've edited the code and able to send payment amount to paypal but when I pay it.. I don't get that additional $30 in my paypal funds but only $5 of subscription.

Can anybody give me any tips to solve this issue. Thank you. I can't share the links since they are all offline.(localhost).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems as though you are authorizing a starting price + additional amounts to start the checkout, and then after approval is given and there is a return from PayPal ... you only capture the starting price, not adding additionals into how much you capture.

Comment: i'm very new in paypal thing.. so you mean capturing and authorizing are two different things?.  But I print_r(ed) the array.. that contains only one value which is combined one.

Comment: If you are using the classic APIs, there is a SetExpressCheckout before approval, DoExpressCheckoutPayment after approval, and possibly a further authorization DoCapture step if you have that enabled.  So there are potentially 3, but definitely 2, different times where you need to know and specify the amount you want.  If you give a different amount where you haven't applied the calculation, then that different amount (in this case, a starting price) is going to be used instead.

Comment: Thanks @Preston.. your main TIPs really helped me.. although this was not the exact solution but that paved my way to go on track. .Thank you again